# Does ArcGIS Server include Tracking Server?

Tags: arcgis-server, tracking-server

I want to create a vehicle tracking application. I have ArcGIS Desktop and ArcGIS Server. Can I create application for real time with these two software? I saw in ESRI site another server called Tracking Server. Does ArcGIS Server include Tracking Server or the Tracking Server is another product?

Comment: Note that with the release of ArcGIS 10.2, ArcGIS GeoEvent Processor for Server is replacing Tracking Server as Esri's primary server technology for real-time GIS.

Answer (score 4):

In the [Tracking Server marketing material](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/tracking-server/common-questions) it says:

> Tracking Server is an independent server product that is not
>   integrated with ArcGIS for Server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use arcgis serer with the tracking extension though. It is an option when you register it.